# add a marker on existing map from data received by web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I want to add a marker into existing google map, from data received by my web service. I get the latitude and the longitude with no problems. But I can´t figure out how to this. Here go my code, and what I try to do:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script>
        function initialize(){
            var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(25,-30),
            zoom:2,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
...
<div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:700px;height:350px; border-radius:20px;"></div>
</div>
...

<script src="../front-end/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jogadoresList").click(function () {
            $("#index").hide();
            $("#selecoes").hide();
            $("#jogador").show();
            initialize();
    });

});
</body>
```

main.js

```
function findByIdLocationTwitterJogador(id){
    console.log('findJTwitterByJogadorrrrrr AQUIIIIIIIIII' + id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURLLocalizacao +'/' + id,
        dataType: "json", // data type of response
        success: renderListLocalizacao
    });
}


function renderListLocalizacao(data) {
    // JAX-RS serializes an empty list as null, and a 'collection of one' as an object (not an 'array of one')
    var list = data == null ? [] : (data.dados instanceof Array ? data.dados : [data.jogo]);

    $.each(list, function(index, jogo) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(jogo.latitude,jogo.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Former About.com Headquarters"
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the "map" object is not visible from the `renderListLocalizacao(...)` function. Note how your `map` is created inside the scope of your `initialize()`

Try making the map a global var. If you dump / look at its value while running that function, I am guessing you will see `map` as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Please set a global map object as follows

```
 <script>
    var globalMap=null;
    function initialize(){
        var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(25,-30),
        zoom:2,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        globalMap=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and in `renderListLocalizacao`

```
  function renderListLocalizacao(data) {
// JAX-RS serializes an empty list as null, and a 'collection of one' as an object (not an 'array of one')
var list = data == null ? [] : (data.dados instanceof Array ? data.dados : [data.jogo]);

$.each(list, function(index, jogo) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(jogo.latitude,jogo.longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: globalMap,
        title:"Former About.com Headquarters"
    });
});
```